# How to open Safari browser using webdriver in MAC OS X 10.7?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to open safari browser using webdriver.

While executing test script it display something in console but browser haven't open.

I want open safari browser same as firefox.

this was display in console

```
Jul 24, 2013 5:47:25 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverServer start
INFO: Server started on port 35351
Jul 24, 2013 5:47:27 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverChannelHandler$1     
operationComplete
INFO: Connection opened
Page Title = Refer Power
Jul 24, 2013 5:47:29 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverServer stop
INFO: Stopping server
```

Comment: I've never used Safari/Mac for selenium.  It also looks like you are using some kind of remote server, not your local machine to run it.  Anyways, the "Page Title = Refer Power" makes me think that it actually is opening up.  Is that your output of the title, and is that the correct page title?

Comment: I am running on my local MAC machine and it display correct result of page title but i didn't see safari browser to open.

Comment: I'm still thinking that you are running it remotely.  Could you post how you are instantiating your SafariDriver?

Comment: WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver

Comment: Does your webdriver.safari.driver system property point to your Safari installation?  That's the only other thing I can think of.

Comment: this was missing but after pointing to safari installation it display error message in safari browser "[  2.648s] [safaridriver.client] Unable to establish a connection with the SafariDriver"